# How to log MaxHeaderBytes header issue in golang

Tags: go

I ran http server in golang with this code

```
// Setup HTTP server.
var server = &http.Server{
    Addr:           ":" + viper.GetString("SERVER_PORT"),
    Handler:        routes.Routers(),
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1, // 1 byte
}
```

Here I set MaxHeaderBytes to 1 byte and it is working fine and I am getting 413 error code if I pass too many headers but unable to log this error, Even middleware is not working for logging

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to log this error" or "even middle ware is not working"? Your question must be specific. Explain exactly what behavior you see, and what you expected instead.  Also, please include all relevant code.

Comment: Do not post  images. Post text only.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having difficulty understanding the question. Do you want to somehow log the fact a client's request was rejected due to its header being larger than the configured limit?

If yes, look at the `ErrorLog` and `ConnState` callbacks of the [`net/http.Server`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) type.

I do not quite get what you mean by

> Even middleware is not working for logging

but if you mean none of the HTTP request handlers you installed (the object returned by `routes.Routers()` in your example) get called, this can be easily explained: a request is only dispatched to the user-provided handlers if it's completely correct from the point of view of the `net/http` machinery.
Hence if you specifically tell the server to reject requests not meeting certain criteria, such requests won't ever be considered correct and reach the user-defined handlers, so your "middleware" has no chance to act on it.